# WP - Remove feature, but only for "new buyers"

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'd like to know how I can handle the situation when I want to remove a "feature" in my Windows Phone App (which you can buy), but it should stay for people who already bought the app.

Example:

I have a ComboBox with the items:

2008
2009
2010
2011

Now I'd like to "remove" the items 2008 and 2009, so there are only the items 2010 and 2011 left. BUT if the User already bought the app (before I've changed the app/updated it), he still should be able to use the items 2008 & 2009.

So something like this:

```
if(receipt.date < 30.09.2014)
 combobox.add(2008);
 combobox.add(2009);
 combobox.add(2010);
 combobox.add(2011);
else
 combobox.add(2010);
 combobox.add(2011);
```

Is this the right way to go (if so, how can I receive the purchase date) or is there another solution to handle this?

Comment: Does your app use a web service?

Comment: no it doesn't... it's an "offline-app"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `CurrentApp.GetAppReceiptAsync` it includes the purchase date in the receipt XML.

See also [Using receipts to verify product purchases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn532258.aspx).